# Setting title of layer with gsconfig?

Tags: geoserver, gsconfig

I use gsconfig in order to create  a layer in geoserver.
This works great but I have noticed that the title of the geoserver layer is the same as the name of the layer.
Is there a way to pass the title name when creating the layer or edit the resource of the layer later with the correct title of the layer?

I use gsconfig 1.0.0.

This is what I do right now:

```
    cat = Catalog(settings.OGC_SERVER['default']['LOCATION'] + "rest", 'user', 'pass')
    ds = cat.get_store("my_store") 
    cat.publish_featuretype(new_table, ds, "EPSG:4326", srs="EPSG:4326")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that the gsconfig library doesn't takes as input parameter the title of the layer.

But alternatively you can use the get_resource() function to get the layers resource, edit the title and save it as:

```
cat = Catalog('localhost..', 'user', 'pass')
resource = cat.get_resource("layer_name", workspace="my_workspace")
resource.title = "that's my title"
cat.save(resource)
```